# Using Zorn's lemma to show that every field has an algebraic closure.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field

**You may have seen that I posted this proof with some questions earlier today. But I found the answer to most of them. Now I have just one question regarding this proof, so I thought it would be better to delete the earlier post and create a new one, since the earlier one didn't get any answers.**

The proof looks big, and the picture is big, but the author says that it is written in very much detail. My question will revolve around the red line, and I will post it after the picture:

[image]

My question is just how does he knows that $\Omega$ has enough elements to do what he does the over the red line? I get why it has enough elements to contain every algebraic extension of F, since an element of an algebraic extension of F, has to be a zero of a polynomial in $F[x]$, and he has made it so that we have enough elements for all possible zeros of all possible polynomials in $F[x]$.

But in the last part of the proof. How does he know that $\Omega$ has enough elements to construct $\bar{F}(\omega)$? I mean, he said that $\Omega$ was strictly bigger than A, so we know that we have more elements than we need for all possible algebraic extensions of F. But "strictly more" and "many more" is not precise?

**Basically: A was created so that it has enough elements for all algebraic extensions of F, but how is it certain that $\Omega$ has enough elements for even one algebraic extension of $\bar{F}$ (the extension $\bar{F}(\omega)$)**?

I must admit that I don't even know why the statement "Since $\Omega$ has many more elements than $\bar{F}$" is true. I know that Zorn's lemma uses the word maximal element, but by definition all we require is that a maximal element is not the entire set, so what is from stopping it from just being the entire set -1 element, er the entire set-"a very small subset"?

**UPDATE:**
I thought of an argument, do you think this works? Wikipedia talks about cantors theorem and a strict subset by taking the set of all subsets, is what I write under correct, and can be put in the proof?

We assume that $\Omega$ is created by taking the union of  "all subsets of A" and "one more element" . Then we have all the A elements embedded in $\Omega$ as the singletons. Since $\bar{F}$ is an algebraic extension it is represented by these singletons.

Now we do as in the proof assume that $f(x)$ is a nonconstant polynomial in $\bar{F}[x]$, by Kroneker's theorem, there exists an extension field K, with an element s. This element is algebraic over $\bar{F}$ since it is a zero of a polynomial in $\bar{F}[x]$. So the set $F(s)$ is created by $k_0+...+k_{n-1}s^{n-1}$ for $k_i \in \bar{F}$. We can associate s with the "one more element", and since $\bar{F}$ is an algebraic extension, every k is associated with the singletons, and every $k_0+...+k_{n-1}s^{n-1}$ is naturally associated with the subset that is the union of the singletons that each k is associated with.

Hence we have enough elements. Does this work?

Comment: Sorry for removing your tags; but this is not really a question about how Zorn's lemma is used or its necessity in the proof, and it's certainly not a set theoretic question. It's a question about a proof in algebra, that every field has an algebraic closure.

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{F}$ is, in particular, an algebraic extension of $F$ by definition.  As such, it will be in bijection with a subset of $A$: to each element $x$ of $\overline{F}$ we have its minimal polynomial $p_x$ over $F$, and then we can use the Axiom of Choice to choose appropriate $i$ to index the roots of $p_x$ that occur in $\overline{F}$.

Next, we're given that $\Omega$ is "strictly larger" than $A$, by which I assume the author means "has cardinality strictly larger than $|A|$".

So because $\overline{F}$ has cardinality at most $|A|$, we know that there cannot be a bijection from $\overline{F}$ onto $\Omega$. As such, no map with domain $\overline{F}$ can surject onto $\Omega$, and so in particular the inclusion map $\iota: \overline{F}\hookrightarrow \Omega$ is not surjective, allowing us to choose $\omega\in \Omega$.

To actually form the proposed field, we take $\overline{F}(\omega)=\overline{F}[\omega]/\langle f\rangle$, which is a field by the fact that $f$ has no zeroes, and hence $\langle f\rangle$ is maximal.

To see that $\Omega$ is large enough to contain $\overline{F}(\omega)$, we note that $[\overline{F}(\omega):\overline{F}]=\deg f$ so $|\overline{F}(\omega)|=|\overline{F}|^{\deg f}$.  Now, $\overline{F}$ won't be finite, but even if it were $\overline{F}(\omega)$ would be finite.  Otherwise $|\overline{F}|=|\overline{F}(\omega)|$.  $\Omega$ is infinite, so we still have $|\Omega|>|\overline{F}(\omega)|$.

Because $|\Omega|>|\overline{F}(\omega)|$, we know that $|\overline{F}(\omega)\setminus \overline{F}|<|\Omega\setminus \overline{F}|$, so there is an injection of $\overline{F}(\omega)$ into $\Omega$ that fixes $\overline{F}$.  Declaring this injection to be a ring homomorphism gives the image the desired structure and field extension of $\overline{F}$ in $\Omega$.

EDIT: Responding to your update, $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is already enough.  Cantor's Theorem says that $|A|<|\mathcal{P}(A)|$, so from what I've written above we know that setting $\Omega$ to be $\mathcal{P}(A)\cup F$ is enough to get "enough elements".  The problem with the way you try assigning elements of $F(s)$ with elements in $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is that your method doesn't retain the ordering of the $k_i$'s.  Of course, as shown above you don't actually need to actually come up with an injection of $F(s)$ to know there is one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I see that it is a long and good answer, but I will need some time to understand it. I hope it is ok I ask about the update since you commented on it, sorry for not asking about your original answer. If I instead do take the cantor set twice, and I identify double singletons $\{\{\omega\}\}$ with elements in the extension fields, and I identify $\{\{\omega_0\},\{\omega_0,\omega_1\},\{\omega_0,\omega_1,\omega_2\}.....\}$ with $k_0+...+k_{n-1}s^{n-1}$, will it work then? Then I have taken care of the ordering?

Comment: And last I wonder if we can use this trick in order to only have to work with the set A, and not with $\Omega$ at all: When we come to the paragraph I have in red we assume that we are working somewhere else, we are not in A(and not in $\Omega$ since we have not defined it). But we show that here $\bar{F}$ still has an algebraic extension(like he does), and now, this extension must then be isomorphic to an element in S(and then this is bigger than the maximal element, so we have a contradiction), since it is an algrebraic extension of F. So can we this way get away from working with $\Omega$?

Comment: @user119615 I assume you meant $k_i$ when you say $\omega_i$.  Your mapping in this case isn't injective; $1+s+\cdots+s^{i-1}+s^{i+1}+\cdots+s^{n-1}$ has the same image $\{\{\{1\}\},\{\{0\},\{1\}\}\}$ (using double singletons doesn't really matter here, we'd have the same with triple singletons, quadruple singletons, etc).  The problem with defining an explicit map of $\overline{F}(\omega)$ into $\Omega$ (or subset of $\Omega$, however you're looking at it) is that you don't know what $\overline{F}(\omega)$ looks like.  For all we know, $\overline{F}$ actually contains $A$, which...

Comment: ...is a real possibility.  This is the main reason why we can't define $\Omega$ to be *exactly* what we need to make sure the construction of $\overline{F}(\omega)$ goes through; we don't have any control over what $\overline{F}$ is, so those elements you added to be $\omega$ or the polynomials in $\omega$ might have already been used.  You could add tons of conditions to what $S$ is, but this is more cumbersome than just picking $\Omega$ to be so large that it doesn't matter.

Comment: If we only took $S$ to be the collection of algebraic extensions of $F$ contained in in $A$, then we'd run into the problem of needing to put more conditions on $S$ again:  $A$ is going to be infinite no matter what, and when $F$ is infinite, we'll have that $F$ and $A$ have the same cardinality.  Given any element $\omega$ that we want to be the root of an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$, this will also be the same size as $A$, so we could (even after deciding on an explicit injection of $F$ into $A$) define $F[x]$ in such a way that it is the whole of $A$.

Comment: This may be a stupid idea, but what about this: We don't even need A at all? Let S be the set of algebraic extensions of F, ordered by field inclusion, where if a field $E_1$ is isomorpic to a subfield of $E_2$ , then $E_1 \leq E_2$. Then S is non-empty since $F \in S$, and we just continue from there showing that $\bar{F}$ if not algebraically closed, there is a field $\bar{F}(s)$ which properly contains $\bar{F}$ and is an element of S?

Comment: How do you show that $S$ actually is a set?  (Hint: it isn't, so you can't)  You need a set from which the algebraic extensions you're considering are drawing their elements from, and you need to pick a set big enough so that the proof will go through.  How do you know which set to pick?  You need to find a bound on the size of an algebraic extension, and to do this you'd likely end up making the set $A$ anyways.  Is there a particular reason you don't seem to like the proof the author has given?

Comment: The reason was that I really didn't understand what is done and how the cardinality arguments came about. But I found another link with almost the same proof where they prove the cardinality arguments in the end: http://tinyurl.com/laxa9sx and it seems like the cardinality arguments are also a consequence of zorns lemma , is zorns lemma behind the cardinalty arguments you and egreg do, like in the article I linked to?(it is the lemma after the main proof) Sorry for beeing slow, I never learned these cardinality arguments.

Comment: Sure, though I'd approach it using the Axiom of Choice instead (which is equivalent to Zorn's Lemma).  Unless your course requires you to be particularly careful about cardinality arguments, I wouldn't worry about it too much.  Otherwise, I'd recommend you read through a brief introduction to the topics of the axiom of choice/zorn's lemma/well ordering theorem and cardinals.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help and time. I just have one more question if that is ok. The fact that you were able to recognize that S defined a particular was was not a set, but maybe a collection or a class(so we can't use zorns lemma on it), how did you learn this? Did you take a particular subject in advanced set theory, or have your red a special book for this?

Comment: Likely just thinking about things lead me to learn this.  The reasoning is not hard: suppose we have even one algebraic extension $K$ of $F$, and choose a fixed element $x_0$ in $K$ not in $F$ (so, in particular, $K$ is not $F$, and we must require that $F$ is not algebraically closed).  We can then create, for every set $x$ not an element of $K$, the set $K_{x}$ given by replacing $x_0$ with $x$.  Taking the obvious bijection $\varphi: K\rightarrow K_x$ and declaring this a field isomorphism makes $K_x$ an algebraic extension of $F$...

Comment: ... Since the class of sets not in $K$ is a proper class, we know that the collection of all algebraic extensions is a proper class (i.e. not a set).  Of course, there's really nothing about this that is specific to fields.  You could have done the same thing with rings, groups, posets, metric spaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is a nonconstant polynomial in $\bar{F}[x]$ having no roots, the field $K=\bar{F}[x]/(f(x))$ is a proper algebraic extension of $\bar{F}$ where $f(x)$ has a root.

Now $|K\setminus\bar{F}|\le|K|<|\Omega|$ and $|\Omega\setminus\bar{F}|=|\Omega|$ by cardinal arithmetic. So you can find an injective map
$$
\varphi\colon K\to\Omega
$$
such that $\varphi(a)=a$ for $a\in\bar{F}$. You can transport the structure of $K$ on $\varphi(K)$ which so becomes a proper field extension of $\bar{F}$ *contained* in $\Omega$, contradicting the maximality of $\bar{F}$.